# Disk cloning for failing disk

Tags: hard-disk, ssd

I have a failing disk with thousands of relocated sectors, and a few pending ones.
This disk need to be cloned to an SSD of equal size.

However, cloning tools fail with a permission denied error somewhere halfway.
I have used Macrium and AOMEI.

Is there any afforable¹ software that can handle these disks?

Any OS except apple. Copy would work, but since it's a system disk and still (magically) boots Windows, I’d like to just clone it. Less hassle for the user.

¹ <sub>affordable, as in cheaper than data recovery service</sub>

Comment: @Izzy you are correct. Meanwhile Acronis is running now, which seems to work. Except that it did 200 GB in 24 hours (of 500). So, the replaced sectors are really slowing things down.

Comment: Thanks again, included as well (you're aware that you can always [edit] your post?) Good luck then! I'm not the MS guy (MS free zone here), so helping you to fill the gaps in your post is the best I can do. Though I've heard Acronis should be doing its job quite well.